# Problem with Google Apps Script maximum execution time

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I'm new to coding and recently I've created a Google script (based on two other scripts) which does the following:

1. Searches for a Gmail draft by its subject line
2. Gets the Gmail draft and uses it as a template to create multiple drafts with unique attachments
3. Puts a confirmation phrase after drafts are created.

Here is the code:

```
//Change these to match the column names you are using for email recepient addresses and merge status column//
var RECIPIENT_COL  = "Email";
var MERGE_STATUS_COL = "M";

//Creates the menu item "Mail Merge" for user to run scripts on drop-down//
function onOpen(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Mail Merge')
  .addItem(' Create Drafts', 'createDrafts').addToUi(); 
}

function createDrafts() {
  // search for the draft Gmail message to merge with by its subject line
  var subjectLine = Browser.inputBox("Select draft " + "to merge with:", "Paste the subject line:", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);

  if (subjectLine === "cancel" || subjectLine == ""){ 
   // if no subject line finish up
   return;
  }

  // get the draft Gmail message to use as a template
  var emailTemplate = getGmailTemplateFromDrafts_(subjectLine);
  emailTemplate.subject = subjectLine;

  // get the data from the active sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  // fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  // assuming row 1 contains our column headings
  var header = data.shift(); 

  // get the index of column named 'M' (Assume header names are unique)
  var draftCreatedColIdx = header.indexOf(MERGE_STATUS_COL);

  var object = data.map(function(row) {  
    // create a new object for next row using the header as a key
    var nextRowObject = header.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex) {
      accumulator[currentValue] = row[currentIndex];      
      return accumulator;
    }, {}) // Use {} here rather than initialAccumulatorValue
    return nextRowObject;
  });

  // loop through all the rows of data
  object.forEach(function(row, rowIdx){

    // only create drafts if mail merge status cell is blank
    if (row[MERGE_STATUS_COL] === ''){

        var msgObj = fillInTemplateFromObject_(emailTemplate, row);
        var attachment_id = "File Name";

        // split the values taken from cell into array
        var pdfName = row[attachment_id].split(', ');
          // initialize files as empty array
          var files = []; 

          // run through cell values and perform search
          for(var j in pdfName){ 
            // perform the search,results is a FileIterator
            var results = DriveApp.getFilesByName(pdfName[j]); 
            // interate through files found and add to attachment results
            while(results.hasNext()) {
        // add files to array
        files.push(results.next());
            }
          }     

        // @see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options
        GmailApp.createDraft(row[RECIPIENT_COL], msgObj.subject, msgObj.text, {htmlBody: msgObj.html, attachments: files});
        // create a confirmation phrase in the first column
        sheet.getRange("A" + (rowIdx + 2)).setValue("DRAFT");    
     }
  }); 
}

/**
 * Get a Gmail draft message by matching the subject line.
 * @param {string} subject_line to search for draft message
 * @return {object} containing the plain and html message body
*/
function getGmailTemplateFromDrafts_(subject_line) {
  try {
    // get drafts
    var drafts = GmailApp.getDrafts();
    // filter the drafts that match subject line
    var draft = drafts.filter(subjectFilter_(subject_line))[0];
    // get the message object
    var msg = draft.getMessage();
    return {text: msg.getPlainBody(), html:msg.getBody()};
  } catch(e) {
    throw new Error("Oops - can't find Gmail draft");
  }
}

/**
 * Filter draft objects with the matching subject linemessage by matching the subject line.
 * @param {string} subject_line to search for draft message
 * @return {object} GmailDraft object
*/
function subjectFilter_(subject_line){
  return function(element) {
    if (element.getMessage().getSubject() === subject_line) {
      return element;
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Fill HTML string with data object.
 * @param {string} template string containing {{}} markers which are replaced with data
 * @param {object} data object used to replace {{}} markers
 * @return {object} message replaced with data
 * H/T https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge
*/
function fillInTemplateFromObject_(template, data) {
  // convert object to string for simple find and replace
  template = JSON.stringify(template);
  // Search for all the variables to be replaced, for instance {{Column name}}
  var templateVars = template.match(/{{([^}]+)}}/g);

  // Replace variables from the template with the actual values from the data object.
  // If no value is available, replace with the empty string.
  for (var i = 0; i < templateVars.length; ++i) {
    // strip out {{ }} 
    var variableData = data[templateVars[i].substring(2, templateVars[i].length - 2)];
    template = template.replace(templateVars[i], variableData || "");
  }
  // convert back to object
  return JSON.parse(template);
}
```

The script works as expected but when I'm trying to process too many rows with too many attachments **it exceeds a 6-minute Google Script maximum execution time.**

While trying to solve this problem I found a simple [script](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/home/announcements/timeconsumingtasksandgoogleappsscriptadd-ons) that uses a `continuationToken` and by doing so never exceeds the limit. **My goal is to try to use the same principle in my own script and to process rows by tens.** Unfortunatelly, I haven't had any luck so far and need some help. Here's the code of the script that I found:

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("List Drive files").addItem('Start', 'start').addToUi();
}

function start() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ui');
  return SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function getDriveFiles(continuationToken) {
  if(continuationToken) {
    var files = DriveApp.continueFileIterator(continuationToken);
  }
  else {
    var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  }
  var i = 0;
  while (files.hasNext() && i < 10) {
    var file = files.next();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow([file.getName(), file.getUrl()]);
    i++;
    if(i == 10) {
      return files.getContinuationToken();
    }
  }
}
```

**ui.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
<div style="text-align:center; margin-top:10px">
<div>Files processed:</div>
<div id="nbOfFilesProcessed">0</div>
<br>
<button id="startButton" class="blue" onclick="start()">Start</button>
<div class="secondary">Close the sidebar to stop the script.</div>
</div>

<script>
function start() {
  document.getElementById("startButton").disabled = true;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getDriveFiles();
}
function onSuccess(continuationToken){
  // If server function returned a continuationToken it means the task is not complete
  // so ask the server to process a new batch.
  if(continuationToken) {
    var nbOfFilesProcessedEl = document.getElementById("nbOfFilesProcessed");
    nbOfFilesProcessedEl.innerHTML = parseInt(nbOfFilesProcessedEl.innerHTML) + 10;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getDriveFiles(continuationToken);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You going to have to be more specific than `need some help`

Comment: I'd like to be able to process the rows in my script by a small batch (10 files) then go back to the client side to call the server again and process a new batch (like in the second script that I've posted). By doing so, as far as I understand, the timer will be reset and I'll never get close to the 6 minutes limit. I'm not entiry sure how to do so, though. That's why I need help

Comment: Well so you just use google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().runBatch(obj); And object contains all the information that you need to run another batch.  At the end of each batch you store the information in properties services or cache service so that when you start another batch it has the current information for the next batch.  And you return back to the .withSuccessHandler() after every batch.  And then you can use a timer to start another batch.

Comment: You still have to stay within your daily quota.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in the code you posted you will have to edit your `createDrafts` function in this way:

- Edit how the function is triggered: you will have to use an HTML ui element to run javascript inside it.
- Edit the `while` loop so that it has a `return` statement when you hit the limit of your batch.
- Create a Javascript function in the HTML ui element that handles the success of the `createDrafts` function and recursively calls it in case that the `continuationToken` is returned.

### Snippets

#### UI Component

You can keep your custom menu and on click add this HTML to a UI dialog.

```js
- code.gs -
//Creates the menu item "Mail Merge" for user to run scripts on drop-down//
function onOpen(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Mail Merge')
  .addItem(' Create Drafts', 'openDialog').addToUi(); 
}
function openDialog() {
  // Display a modal dialog box with custom HtmlService content.
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
      .createHtmlOutputFromFile('Dialog')
      .setWidth(250)
      .setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Create Drafts');
}
```

```html
- Dialog.html -
<!-- The UI will be very similar to the one you found, I will keep only the strictly necessary statements for this example -->
<div>
<button id="startButton" onclick="startBatch()">Start</button>
</div>

<script>
function startBatch() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).createDrafts();
}
function onSuccess(continuationToken){
  // If server function returned a continuationToken it means the task is not complete
  // so ask the server to process a new batch.
  if(continuationToken) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).createDrafts(continuationToken);
  }
}
</script>
```

#### Apps Script Component

```
function createDrafts(continuationToken) {
 var batchLimit = 10;
 // ...
 // run through cell values and perform search
 for(var j in pdfName){ 
     // perform the search,results is a FileIterator
     if (continuationToken) {
         var results = DriveApp.continueFileIterator(continuationToken);
     } else {
         var results = DriveApp.getFilesByName(pdfName[j]);
     } 
     // interate through files found and add to attachment results
     let i = 0;
     while(results.hasNext() && i<batchLimit) {
         // add files to array
         files.push(results.next());
         i++;
         if (i === batchLimit) {
             return results.getContinuationToken();
         }
     }
 }
```

### Final considerations

As an improvement to your batch operation, I would save all the user inputs so that you will be able to continue the script without prompting for it again. You can either pass these values to the return function on a javascript object or save them in the cache with the CacheService utility.

Moreover, try to find the correct trade off between execution time and batch limit: A small batch limit will never hit the time limit but will consume your quota very fast.

### References:

[Client Side API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#index.html)

[Cache Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service)

[Apps Script UI](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for your reply. You made it all very clear and now it seems to be working. The only 2 tiny problems that I have right now is that these lines of code from the html file don't update the number of drafts created: 

`var nbOfFilesProcessedEl = document.getElementById("nbOfFilesProcessed"); nbOfFilesProcessedEl.innerHTML = parseInt(nbOfFilesProcessedEl.innerHTML) + 10;` 

Also, I'm struggling to find a way to insert my confirmation phrase (DRAFT) after each batch of 10 has been processed. 

These changes would help me to see that the script is running succesfully.

Comment: Did you put `<div id="nbOfFilesProcessed">0</div>` in your html dialog?
"Also I'm struggling to find a way to insert my confirmation phrase (DRAFT) after each batch of 10 has been processed" What do you mean? Which code instruction insert the confirmation phrase? If this solution solves your problem you should accept the answer and make another question for your other problems. This will make your post useful to others in the Stack Overflow community and to keep things more organized. Thanks!

Comment: I did put the line of code you've mentioned but it doesn't update the html file. This is the code from my original script that was used to put a confirmation phrase: `sheet.getRange("A" + (rowIdx + 2)).setValue("DRAFT");` It puts a word "DRAFT" in the first column after all rows are processed. It was useful when there were some 10-20 rows to process but with some 100 rows it's quilte useless, because there is no visual indicator that the script is actually working correctly unless you go to the draft folder and reload it or wait until the script stops. And yes, I will accept yout answer.

Comment: Hey Michael you just upvoted it. [Accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Dear Alessandro, I've just run a final test with some 70 rows with two attachments each and the script with your modifications still stops after about 6 minutes of working. Maybe I'm doing something wrong but it doesn't have any effect for some reason.

Comment: Please share your final script and a test spreadsheet so I can help you better.

Comment: Dear Alessandro, here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1s428BhFahQ38X33LeaL1vHA8o8B8zMDS?usp=sharing) to a Google Drive folder where you will find: 1) A spreadsheet with the script in question, 2) A doc file with the text that you can copy/paste in your Gmail draft folder to use as a template, 3) Two random PDF files to use as attachments. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hi @Michael, I see that you are using the return inside of a closure. This won't work as intended. Try to change the `forEach()` in a normal for loop that remains in the `createDrafts` scope. This will allow you to return to the success handler when you hit the batch limit. Another aspect of your code is that you are using the batch limit only for the drives calls. I suspect that creating the drafts will cause timeout errors as well. You should implement a similar logic on that too.